# vb.net - Run JS from HTML

Tags: javascript, html, vb.net, multithreading, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to run a JS code same as I would run it from console on webpage.

In code below "myhtml" is string with HTML from page I want to get value of #green

Simpliest answer would be to use webbrowser, but I can't as I'm not working with single-threaded application (so I'd get errors obviously).

The "myhtml" has external scripts that need to be loaded, so answer I'm looking is something like webbrowser that I can use in multithreaded application.

Code I've tried (changed JScript with HTML in js.Language):

```
Dim js As MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass = New MSScriptControl.ScriptControlClass()
js.AllowUI = False
js.Language = "HTML"
js.Reset()
js.AddCode("myhtml")

Dim parms As Object() = New Object() {11}
Dim result As Integer = CInt(js.Run("alert(document.getElementById('green').value)", parms))
MsgBox(result)
```

With result of:

> A script engine for the specified language can not be created.

Comment: HTML is a markup language, not a scripting language. So that's why your getting that error.


Is there a reason you can't use javascript?

Comment: I want to use it but I need html along with js so code would work. As in code above, alert wouldn't work because there is no html code with id "green".

Comment: if you want to run javascript independent of the browser, your going to have to do all of the behind the scenes stuff the browser does for you. Which will include parsing the HTML yourself

Comment: I know that and it already does get html page but I just need an answer.